# What an appropriate MySQL datatype for about 6kb of text?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

What an appropriate MySQL datatype for about 6kb of text?

I've looked this sorta question elsewhere but people seem very vague about the size of text they are storing. I've also seen a suggestion to link to just a table of textdata. Would this be appropriate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`LONGTEXT` type would better for storing large text content.

There are 4 kinds of DATATYPES

1. TINYTEXT
2. TEXT
3. MEDIUMTEXT
4. LONGTEXT

Acoording to [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html) .

LONGTEXT | 4,294,967,295 (232−1) bytes =  4 GiB